# Нужна критика кода

Tags: html, css, инспекция-кода

```css
*{
 transition: all 1s ease;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.carts {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.carts-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.big-con {
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 540px;
  height: 540px;
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/eiVqnp/big.png) no-repeat center/contain;
  position: relative;
}

.big-con::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/nPLqnp/boot_part.png) no-repeat center/contain;
  width: 9%;
  height: 9%;
  left: -4.5%;
  top: 42.7%;
}

.big-con::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://svgshare.com/i/87A.svg) no-repeat center/contain;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  left: 1%;
  top: 1%;
}

.middle-con {
  height: 255px;
  position: relative;
  width: 540px;
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/iv2QL9/rec.png) no-repeat center/contain;
}

.middle-con::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/imns09/boot2.png) no-repeat center/contain;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  left: -44%;
  top: -14.7%;
}

.right-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.last-left {
  width: 255px;
  height: 255px;
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/dpZi7p/small1.png) no-repeat center/contain;
}

.last-right {
  width: 255px;
  height: 255px;
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/jb1kL9/small2.png) no-repeat center/contain;
}

.last-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media(max-width: 1270px) {
  .big-con {
    width: 486px;
    height: 486px;
  }
  .middle-con {
    width: 486px;
    height: 229.5px;
  }
  .last-left {
    height: 229.5px;
    width: 229.5px;
  }
  .last-right {
    height: 229.5px;
    width: 229.5px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1020px) {
  .big-con {
    width: 378px;
    height: 378px;
  }
  .middle-con {
    width: 378px;
    height: 178.5px;
  }
  .last-left {
    height: 178.5px;
    width: 178.5px;
  }
  .last-right {
    height: 178.5px;
    width: 178.5px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 820px) {
  .carts-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .big-con {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .middle-con {
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 570px) {
  .big-con {
    width: 270px;
    height: 270px;
  }
  .middle-con {
    width: 270px;
    height: 127.5px;
  }
  .last-left {
    height: 127.5px;
    width: 127.5px;
  }
  .last-right {
    height: 127.5px;
    width: 127.5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="carts">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carts-wrapper">

      <div class="big-con"></div>

      <div class="right-wrapper">
        <div class="middle-con"></div>
        <div class="last-wrapper">
          <div class="last-left"></div>
          <div class="last-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Собственно: потратил день на верстку вот этого блока.
Промежуточный вопрос: почему на короне буквы s(сделана в svg) иногда , при некоторых разрешениях появляется горизонтальная черная линия.
Главный вопрос: правильно ли я все сделал? Прошу конструктивной критики в отношении кода. Можно ли было сделать данный адаптивный блок проще? В каких местах допущены непростительные костыли? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Сейчас перепишу код на свой ладн, но я порекомендовал бы отдельные от ботинка части соединить в PS и не париться с `::after` и `::before`. Прозрачным фон сохраняется прозрачным при сохранении картинки в PNG формате. В JPEG/JPG прозрачный фон заменяется на белый

Comment: 2 - В PS или на онлайн ресурсах оптимизировать картинки. 
3 - зайти на сайт https://gtmetrix.com и проверить страницу на скорость загрузки, оптимизацию кода и т.д. (если ты работаешь с файлами на сервере в инете). P.S проверил на GTmetrix - сайт подтвердил мои слова - надо оптимизировать изображения... Да, это не совсем касается твоего кода, но все же

Comment: `*{transition: all 1s ease}` -  очень очень плохо глобально навешивать стили такого рода